# Android D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5 Infinite Log

Tags: android, kotlin

We're testing with the same application.

Galaxy S9 is
D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5 is output once.

The Galaxy S20 is
The log D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5 is output indefinitely.

I think this is happening because the screen ratio is not right for each device.

I want to know the cause or the solution.
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide more context and some code. At the moment it is pretty hard (if not impossible) for someone to give you an answer.

Comment: Same here. It just keeps printing "D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5". I'm using java and also a Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using kotlin. But I used java for my application. I was also getting that log output continuously. the reason for the infinite log saying "**D/DecorView: semSetRoundedCorners: 5**" was the updating text view within a listener for the sensor event. I checked the code part by part carefully. And finally I found it logs that message when I update the text view within the listener. Check whether you are updating any UI component within a listener or something like an another thread where you have to use **runOnUIThread()** This is listener code for the sensor that I was using

```
        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                int x = (int)values[0];
                int y = (int)values[1];
                int z = (int)values[2];
                if(outputStream != null) {
                    if (x <= 2 && x >= -2) {
                        carActions.setParkingMode();
                    }

                    if (x < -2) {
                        if(y < -3) {
                            carActions.turnLeft();
                        }else if(y > 3){
                            carActions.turnRight();
                        }else{
                            carActions.goForward();
                        }
                    }

                    if (x > 2) {
                        if(y < -3) {
                            carActions.turnLeft();
                        }else if(y > 3){
                            carActions.turnRight();
                        }else{
                            carActions.goBackward();
                        }
                    }
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {


// as you can see below I have commented text view updating out. 
// It helped me to solve the continuous log output



//                        textView.setText(Arrays.toString(new int[]{x, y, z}));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }
        }, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```